# Using Python and Selenium I am unable to get to elements in overlaying model

Tags: python, selenium

In my test I have to click a button to add an item to the cart.  At that point a model dialog comes up and allows some options and links, one of which I am trying to click; View Cart and Checkout.

Every attempt I make to find my element with find_element_by fails with a NoSuchElementException.  Doesn't matter how I try to find it; ID, Class, Link Text, etc.

I have tried setting up WebDriverWait in a try/catch statement to see if pausing for the model to be added to the page would help, and it doesn't.  I have also checked to see if there is another window or frame to switch to, but there is only the one window.

Are there any other ways to get what I need done, or troubleshooting steps that I can do to figure this out?

Below is what Firefox shows the HTML to be.

```
<div class="summary">
    <dl></dl>
    <a class="bb-button" href="/shopping/cart">View Cart and Checkout</a>
<div class="continue"></div>
```

The python I have written is:

```
    product_details.addDocumentToCart('Printed Edition')

    try:
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.CLASS_NAME, 'bb-button'))
        print 'bb-button found'
    except:
        print 'bb-button not found'

    windows = self.driver.window_handles
    print 'Windows after: ' + str(len(windows))

    element = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('bb-button')
    element.click()
```

The messages I printed out return:

added_to_cart-container not found
and
Windows after: 1

The error I get when running this is:

NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"bb-button"}

Comment: Could it be that the overlay window is inside an iframe?

Comment: The only iframe in the page is the html right above where this overlay html starts, but it is separate from this as the iframe tag gets closed before this model overlay is added.

Comment: Did you try this: put in `import pdb ; pdb.set_trace()` break before the line which accesses the element. Then open Firefox Web inspector when the test code pauses and use it to poke around the elements to see what could be wrong.

Comment: I added the import pdb ; pdb.set_trace() and checked the resulting HTML with Web Inspector.  It appears that the HTML that I am looking for doesn't appear when Selenium is running.  I put a try/catch around the button click that should launch this model, and the button is clicking, I just don't get the model.  So this is different behavior than I see when I walk through the site manually and check the HTML with Web Inspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mikko, with your advice about the pbd.set_trace() I was able to discover that my problem was really with the button that I thought was being clicked but wasn't. Further troubleshooting showed that my addDocumentToCart() method was clicking the wrong element, and so my model didn't come up, but no error was generated which lead me to believe that things were working when the really were not.